# concat_ws removes null string from output in spark data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is the Output of my data frame

```
val finaldf.show(false)

+------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------+-----------+
|DataPartition     |TimeStamp                |Source_organizationId|Source_sourceId|FilingDateTime           |SourceTypeCode|DocumentId|Dcn       |DocFormat|StatementDate            |IsFilingDateTimeEstimated|ContainsPreliminaryData|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor|ContainsRestatement|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset|ThirdPartySourceCode|ThirdPartySourcePriority|SourceTypeId|ThirdPartySourceCodeId|FFAction|!||
+------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------+-----------+
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|4298009288           |80             |2017-09-28T23:00:00+00:00|10K           |null      |171105584 |ASFILED  |2017-07-31T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2017-07-31T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |-300                   |SS                  |1                       |3011835     |1000716240            |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-21T12:09:23+00:00|4295904170           |364            |2017-08-08T17:00:00+00:00|10Q           |null      |null      |null     |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |-300                   |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-21T12:09:23+00:00|4295904170           |365            |2017-10-10T17:00:00+00:00|10K           |null      |null      |null     |2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |-300                   |SS                  |1                       |3011835     |1000716240            |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-21T12:17:49+00:00|4295904170           |365            |2017-10-10T17:00:00+00:00|10K           |null      |null      |null     |2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |-300                   |SS                  |1                       |3011835     |1000716240            |I|!|       |
```

When  do `concat_ws` `null` is getting removed from the row .

```
val finaldf = diff.foldLeft(tempReorder){(temp2df, colName) => temp2df.withColumn(colName, lit("null"))}
//finaldf.show(false)

val headerColumn = data.columns.toSeq
val header = headerColumn.mkString("", "|^|", "|!|").dropRight(3)

val finaldfWithDelimiter=finaldf.select(concat_ws("|^|",finaldf.schema.fieldNames.map(col): _*).as("concatenated")).withColumnRenamed("concatenated", header)
finaldfWithDelimiter.show(false)
```

And I get below output

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|DataPartition|^|TimeStamp|^|Source_organizationId|^|Source_sourceId|^|FilingDateTime|^|SourceTypeCode|^|DocumentId|^|Dcn|^|DocFormat|^|StatementDate|^|IsFilingDateTimeEstimated|^|ContainsPreliminaryData|^|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|^|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor|^|ContainsRestatement|^|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset|^|ThirdPartySourceCode|^|ThirdPartySourcePriority|^|SourceTypeId|^|ThirdPartySourceCodeId|^|FFAction|!||
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|SelfSourcedPrivate|^|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|^|4298009288|^|80|^|2017-09-28T23:00:00+00:00|^|10K|^|171105584|^|ASFILED|^|2017-07-31T00:00:00+00:00|^|false|^|false|^|2017-07-31T00:00:00+00:00|^|1.0|^|false|^|-300|^|SS|^|1|^|3011835|^|1000716240|^|I|!|                                                                                                                                                                 |
|SelfSourcedPublic|^|2017-11-21T12:09:23+00:00|^|4295904170|^|364|^|2017-08-08T17:00:00+00:00|^|10Q|^|2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00|^|false|^|false|^|2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00|^|1.0|^|false|^|-300|^|SS|^|1|^|3011836|^|1000716240|^|I|!|                                                                                                                                                                                       |
|SelfSourcedPublic|^|2017-11-21T12:09:23+00:00|^|4295904170|^|365|^|2017-10-10T17:00:00+00:00|^|10K|^|2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00|^|false|^|false|^|2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00|^|1.0|^|false|^|-300|^|SS|^|1|^|3011835|^|1000716240|^|I|!|
```

In the output `DocumentId` which was null is replaced.

Not able to figure out what am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`concat_ws` does remove `null` columns in the concatenation process.  If you want to keep a placeholder for every `null` in the concatenated result, one approach would be to create a `Map` of type-dependent `colName -> nullValue` for `na.fill()` to transform the dataframe before the concatenation, as shown below:

```
val df = Seq(
  (new Integer(1), "a"),
  (new Integer(2), null),
  (null, "c")
).toDF("col1", "col2")

df.withColumn("concat", concat_ws("|", df.columns.map(col): _*)).
  show
// +----+----+------+
// |col1|col2|concat|
// +----+----+------+
// |   1|   a|   1|a|
// |   2|null|     2|
// |null|   c|     c|
// +----+----+------+

val naMap = df.dtypes.map( t => t._2 match {
  case "StringType" => (t._1, "(n/a)")
  case "IntegerType" => (t._1, 0)
  case "LongType" => (t._1, 0L)
  // cases for other types ...
} ).toMap
// naMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = 
//   Map(col1 -> 0, col2 -> (n/a))

df.na.fill(naMap).
  withColumn("concat", concat_ws("|", df.columns.map(col): _*)).
  show
// +----+-----+-------+
// |col1| col2| concat|
// +----+-----+-------+
// |   1|    a|    1|a|
// |   2|(n/a)|2|(n/a)|
// |   0|    c|    0|c|
// +----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: So do i have to write naMap for all of my columns ?...How can i incorporate in my solution ...Basically three two are there to avoid null First is withColumns and then fill ?Can you please edit in my code .. And null as string also be removed ?

Comment: You only need to set up the types of columns which might consist of null in `naMap` to specify what null should be replaced with accordingly.  For instance, the `naMap` in my example covers columns of type String, Int, or Long which might have null.  In your case, simply apply `na.fill(naMap)` before `select`, like, `val finaldfWithDelimiter = finaldf.na.fill(naMap).select(...)...`

Comment: @LeoC I am sorry but still not working for me `naMap` do i have to create naMap ?

Comment: Yes, you create `naMap` and apply `na.fill(naMap)` to `finaldf` before performing concatenation.  Note that what I suggested is just a way of null-filling without supplying specific columns.  Method [na.fill()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions@fill(valueMap:Map[String,Any]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) has a few variants, hence you can pick whichever best suits your use case.  For example you can pick one that lets you supply a specific list of columns of the same type.

Comment: This solution modifies the original columns, take this in mind, it could be an issue for some use cases.

Comment: @ruloweb, yes it's meant to be a generalized solution for handling `null` across columns of a dataframe, hence my sample dataset showing columns additional to the one being `concat`-ed.

Answer (score 2):

Since `concat_ws` ignore the columns that contains `null` you will have to handle them.

One solution is to create a `Map` of type-dependent `colName -> nullValue` for `na.fill()` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48737449/2211721), however you will have to specify all the cases.

Another approach, since you want to obtain a `String`, is to use `format_string` function:

```scala
// Proof of concept in Scala (I don't have the compiler to test it).
df
.withColumn(
  "concat",
  format_string(
    (for (c <- df.columns) yield "%s").mkString("|"),
    df.columns.map(col): _*
  ),
)

/*
  Same solution tested in PySpark.

  format_string(
    '|'.join(['%s' for c in df.columns]),
    *df.columns
  )
*/
```

in this way you will avoid the `Map` definition and it will be placed an empty string for any `null` value in the dataframe columns.

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that the original columns are not modified, if you look at @Leo C solution, the values for col1 and col2 are being modified, and form some use cases that could be an issue.

Comment: The disadvantage is that null values will be replaced with the 'null' string.

Comment: @ruloweb no, it doesn’t place “null” but only “”. Therefore you would obtain something like: “col1||col3” if only col2 is null.

Comment: Well, it actually does it in my test, at least in spark 2.4.5: 

val df = List(("a", null, "c"), ("a", "b", "c")).toDF("val1", "val2", "val3")
df.withColumn("concat", format_string((for (c <- df.columns) yield "%s").mkString("|"), df.columns.map(col): _*))
  .show

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an `udf` like:

```
val concatUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf((columns: Seq[String]) =>
  columns.map(c => if (c == null) "" else c).reduceLeft((a, b) => s"$a:$b"))

df.withColumn("concatenated", concatUDF(array(columns.map(col): _*)))
```

where `array` is `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array`. This won't replace the original columns and will return empty strings for null values, or whatever you want it to be replaced (`if (c == null) ""`).

Also, you can extend the UDF to support multiple types.